# Anime rendering; ray shadows odd results

Tags: shaders

I've been trying to render anime style characters in blender's internal render using opengl rendering; I can get things to look okay as long as things don't have shadows, but as soon as I turn shadows on things get weird. In particular, the shading freaks out and puts square shadows everywhere on the model and remove shadows from areas on the model where there would normally be shadows.

[image]
[image]

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: could it be a problem with the normals of the mesh?

Comment: First, open *Object Data* tab > *Geometry Data* rollout and press *Clear Custom Split Normals* if the button is called like that. Then in Edit mode `W` > *Remove Doubles* and then `Ctrl`+`N` to recalculate normals (all selected for both cases). If that doesn't help please [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) at least part of the problem mesh.

Comment: Here's the model [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1479" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1479/)

Comment: Seems like it could be something with shadows on the material. If turning off ray tracing shadows for the sun lamp, these artifacts *mostly* go away (not all of them). Hard to tell more about Toon shader in BI though.

Comment: is there a different way to cast shadows while also keeping that specific node and shader setup?